Integrating AAD B2C with Entra ID
I followed the instructions in this Microsoft document  to integrate Entra ID with B2C.
As listed in the "Register a Microsoft Entra app" section of the aforementioned document, I registered an application in the Entra ID tenant and set the redirect URI to: https://your-B2C-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp.
In the B2C tenant, the registered application has https://localhost:/signin-oidc as the redirect URI.
I am using a sign-in/sign-up user flow in B2C and have added Entra ID provider to it.
I have a Blazor server-side application. In Program.cs, I have the following:
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
options =>
{
  //code
  //code
options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
{
  context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "Authentication Failed";
  return Task.CompletedTask;
};

 options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
 {
   return Task.CompletedTask;
 };
 options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived = context =>
 {
   return Task.CompletedTask;
 };
 options.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
 {
   return Task.CompletedTask;
 };
}

When I try to authenticate Entra ID user, the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived, OnTokenResponseReceived, and OnTokenValidation events happen in sequence and the application gets redirected to the URI in B2C registered application redirect but I get "This site cannot be reached" error. It looks like the ClientSecret for the B2C registered application doesn't work when the redirect is from Entra ID.
To test this I removed the ClientSecret from B2C configuration and the authentication fails.
How can I make this work?
I did online research but did not find any solution specific to the problem that I am facing.
UPDATE
I added Google as an external IDP and I get successfully redirected to my website. I think certificate may not be an issue here, although I have updated it. Attaching a screenshot of the Dev Tools when I try authenticating against Entra ID:

Also, I am not sure if this makes any difference but the Supported Account Types is "Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant" for the application registered in the Entra ID tenant and I using sign-in/sign-up user flow (not custom policy) in B2C.

"but I get "This site cannot be reached" error" Where do you see this error? OnAuthorizationCodeReceived gets called by the OpenIdConnect middleware. Where does the browser get redirected to after /signin-oidc?

The browser gets redirected to https://localhost: which is the redirect URI set in the application registered in B2C tenant.  I see the error message on body of the page. On the address bar, I see the exclamation mark which when I click. has the message "Your connection to this site is not secure". That's why I guessing it could be something to do with certificate or the ClientSecret of the B2C application.

"Your connection to this site is not secure" usually means that the HTTPS page was loaded using an untrusted certificate. I would put money on you initially loading your site using HTTP (rather than HTTPS) and after authenticating you're being redirected to the HTTPS version that is using an untrusted, probably developer, certificate.

The site loads fine with the certificate showing as valid. I can do a B2C authentication and it redirects without a problem. It is when I use the Entra ID idp that I get the problem. Following is a portion from my launchSettings.json:
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61949",
"sslPort": 44393
}
If it is the certificate issue, how do I go about fixing it?

So, I found out that was options.SaveTokens = true; was causing the issue.
I removed that and instead used:
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
{
  context?.Properties?.StoreTokens(new[] {
  new AuthenticationToken{
      Name="access_token",
      Value=context.TokenEndpointResponse != null ? context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken : string.Empty
}
 });
 return Task.CompletedTask;
 };

Now the redirection is working fine.
